# DotNetZip fails with "stream does not support seek operations"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stream, dotnetzip

I am using DotNetZip in C# to unzip from a stream as follows:

```
public static void unzipFromStream(Stream stream, string outdir)
{   //omit try catch block
    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(stream)){
        foreach (ZipEntry e in zip){
            e.Extract(outdir, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
        }
    }
}
```

stream is obtained using

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream fs = client.OpenRead(url);
```

However, I got the following exception

```
exception during extracting zip from stream System.NotSupportedException: This stream does not support seek operations.
at System.Net.ConnectStream.get_Position()
at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Read(Stream zipStream, TextWriter statusMessageWriter, Encoding encoding, EventHandler`1 readProgress)
```

On the server side(ASP.NET MVC 4), returning `FilePathResult` or `FileStreamResult` both caused this exception.

Should I obtain the stream differently on the client side? Or how to make server return a "seekable" stream? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to download the data to a file or to memory, and then create a `FileStream` or a `MemoryStream`, or some other stream type that supports seeking. For example:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(url, filename);
using (var fs = File.OpenRead(filename))
{
    unzipFromStream(fs, outdir);
}
File.Delete(filename);
```

Or, if the data will fit into memory:

```
byte[] data = client.DownloadData(url);
using (var fs = new MemoryStream(data))
{
    unzipFromStream(fs, outdir);
}
```

Comment: thanks, Jim! is the data size limited only by memory? or also by contrains in C#?

Comment: @green `MemoryStream` has some size limitations (`Int32.MaxValue` bytes at the max, but it will likely fail before then with OutOfMemoryExceptions). `FileStream` is only limited by the size of your hard drive.

Comment: If using HttpWebRequest which returns response as stream instead of Byte(), then need to reset position with "stream.position=0" before passing it to ZipFile.Read(stream) method to avoid this error message.